# loading config file when running a go application with intellij

Tags: go, intellij-idea

I use MacOS Mojave with IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2.

I wrote a go application that loads a config file from the directory of my project. I created an `InitConfig()` function to load the JSON file into a struct. this is thee code of my `Config.go` file

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/tkanos/gonfig"
    "log"
)

type Configuration struct {
    WebServerPort   int
    DbName string
    DbUser string
    DbPassword string
    DbPort int
    CertFile string
    KeyFile string
    EnableHttps bool
}

var AppConfiguration Configuration

func InitConfig() {
    AppConfiguration = Configuration{}
    err := gonfig.GetConf(ExPath + "/config/config.json", &AppConfiguration)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not parse configuration file: %v",err)
    }
}
```

I use a variable called `ExPath` that contains the current directory of the running binary, I created it with the following code (Path.go):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

var ExPath string

func InitPath() {
    ex, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not get executable path: %v",err)
    }
    ExPath = filepath.Dir(ex)
}
```

when I try to run or debug the application, intellij is creating a directory where it compiles and runs the application, how can I tell it to also copy the json file?

when I try to run/debug my App I get:

```
could not parse configuration file: open /private/var/folders/60/qzt2pgs173s4j_r6lby_mw1c0000gn/T/config/config.json: no such file or directory
```

I checked and that directory really doesn't contain my config directory. so.. is there a way to let intellij know it should copy it before executing my project?

thanks!

Comment: `os.Getwd()`, gives you current working directory, `cwd` and `executable path` were different things, were you creating the config file in the first place.

Comment: @nilsocket - I can't use Getwd function because i don't want to use the working directory in case I execute the file from a different directory, and for some reason Getwd returns the root directory of my project and not the working directory I set in my run/debug profile

Comment: who is creating the config file, if it's you then you can consider having a fixed path, you are not calling `filepath.Dir()` in `InitConfig()`. It's confusing try to report your problem with minimal and complete example

Comment: @nilsocket - thanks for all the valuable information. it appears I just needed to configure my run/debug profile better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the solution is simple. all I needed is to set the "Output Directory" of my run/debug configuration to my project's directory. and then intellij executes the file in that same directory and it can find `/config/config.json`.